# 2D vector lookup [x;y]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a matrix, with two coordinates `[i;j]`

I'm trying to automatize a lookup:

> [image]
>
> As an example, this would have the coordinates of `[1;2]`

Here's a table of all the coordinates:

[image]

So here, obviously `[1;2]` would equate to `143,33`

---

*To simplify the issue*:

---

I'll try to go step by step over what I'm trying to do to make the question bit less confusing.

Think of what I'm trying to do as a function, `lookup(i, j) => value`

Now, refer to the second picture (table)

1. I find all rows containing index `[i]` *(inside column C)* and then
2. **only for those rows** find row containing index `[j]` *(inside column D ∩ for rows from previous step)*
3. Return `[i;j]` value

So if u invoked `lookup(2, 4)`

1. Find all rows matching `i = 2`

   - Row `5`: `i = 2` ; `j = 3`
   - Row `6`: `i = 2` ; `j = 4`
   - Row `7`: `i = 2` ; `j = 5`
2. Lookup column j for `j=4` from found rows

   - Found row `6`: `i = 2` ; `j = 4`.
3. Return value (offset for yij column = `143,33`)

Now this isn't an issue algorhitmically speaking, but I have no idea how to go about doing this with excel formulas.

---

PS: I know this is reltively simple [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) issue but I would prefer formulas
PSS: I removed what I tried to make the question more readable.

Comment: What is the input and what is the output? Can you give specific examples as it relates to the screen shots you shared? It's a little unclear for me personally. Given [this] information I want [this] output to be [here] kind of thing would help. Although others may understand your question as is

Comment: @urdearboy I tried, though perhaps it was a it confusing with the formulas. Basically, if you refer to the first picture, the -> **axis (1st row) represents the `[j]` coordinate, and the 1st column represents the `[i]` coordinate. `[i;j]` = `[1;2]`.**  (hence the `i/j` in top left cell) Now if you refer to the second picture, and look up in the column heading `i` for `1` and column heading `j` for 2, you'll find adjacent to it the value 143,33 which I'm trying to get.

I'd gladly add more detail to it, but to be frank, I'm not sure how without making it even more confusing.

Comment: To make it really barebones, the matrices are ssentially irrelevant. In programming terms,  i need a function with two parameters `lookup(Xcoordinate, Ycoordinate): value)` which would look it up inside the table, which you can refer to in 2nd picture. So first it would look up the `i` column for Xcoordinate value and then the `j` colum for Ycoordinate value and return the resulting row - where both the I and J need to intersect (be found on the same row) -  *(and I'm returning an offset of that value for 143,33, but that's just some extra sauce on top of the function)*

Comment: In the top picture what are all the other values? Where does 283,25 come into play? I still don't understand where the output goes. Is the output going in the first or second picture?

Comment: Oh, the output goes into the selected cell. The other numbers are carry-over from other formulae. My apologies, I replaced the picture with something  much more straightforward! :-) Should hoperfully be much more understandable now!

Comment: makes much more sense. Thanks for updating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`, which return `0` for not found values:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$4:$C$18=$I4)*($D$4:$D$18=J$3)*$E$4:$E$18)
```

or `AGGREGATE`, which returns an error that can be hidden by the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(($C$4:$C$18=$I12)*($D$4:$D$18=J$3)))*$E$4:$E$18,1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Aggregate - nice. + 1

Comment: Looks like i really should put more time looking into sumproduct. Awesome, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMIFS` here assuming you will not have exact duplicate combinations of `[i, j]`. If you did have a duplicate combination, the amounts will be summed and placed in the corresponding cell

---

In cell `B2` place this equation: `=SUMIFS($Q$2:$Q$16,$P$2:$P$16,B$1,$O$2:$O$16,$A2)` and drag across and over as needed

[image]

---

***IF*** you want to convert the **0's** to **blanks** you can nest the above formula inside a text formatter like so:

*`=TEXT([formula], "0;-0;;@")`*